# Why do I lose data on portable hard drive with Windows 10 NTFS?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs

Over the last 9 years I have been using standard SATA hard drives in docking stations as portable hard drives formatted with NTFS.  I use them with Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Linux, and now Windows 10.  3 times now when using with Windows 10 I have experienced file system truncation where about a third of the hard drive data is non-recoverable.  I am beginning to wonder if this is a Windows 10 thing.  I know NTFS requires a proper shutdown procedure to protect data in flight.  Like I said, I have not had this problem in the past so Windows 10 is the only thing that has changed in my equation.

Is there a proper procedure when using NTFS SATA drives as removable drives? What is that process? Assuming the drives are healthy, what is the most likely reason for this data loss?

Comment: You should think about rewording your question as at the moment it looks like a polling question (which we don't allow). As it stands anybody could answer "yes" or "no" but it wouldn't help you. Please try to be more specific if you want a proper answer.

Comment: Are the drives fine after reformatting? Are you sure they aren't just pre-failure and you've happened to hit upon this while using windows 10?

Comment: @djsmiley2k - Excellent question - the problem occurs on multiple different drives.  I fix the NTFS partition using software tools and continue to use.  I recover from backups when possible.  The drives perform flawlessly on other systems.  I will try to avoid using my portable drives on the Windows 10 system until I get some feedback on the problem...

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks for the feedback.  I have altered the question title to reflect my particular problem.

Comment: I use NTFS because I feel it is better/safer than FAT32.  I would prefer to use EXT3, EXT4, or BTRFS but Windows can't read these partitions..

Comment: Was it a drive over 2TB ? What adapter did you use ?

Comment: I removed the poll question (is anyone having this issue?), but this still leaves this post without a real question. Are you looking for a solution? Then please say so.

Comment: `I know NTFS requires a proper shutdown procedure to protect data in flight` no, NTFS has journal for recovery after a sudden power loss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is most likely due to unplugging the drive while data is being written. Be sure the external HDD is optimized for quick removal and be sure to "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" and **wait for notification that it is safe to remove the HDD**.

Open *Device Manager*, click on *Disk drives* to expand it and right-click on the external HDD to check its *Properties*.

[image: External HDD in Device Manager]

If you want to prevent write-caching, check *Quick removal*. However, even with this option checked, it takes a finite time to write data to the drive, so **always** remove the drive *safely* and wait for notification that it is now safe to disconnect it. [In some cases, I've had to perform a full shutdown to get the HDD released.]

Comment: thanks for the feedback - I will set this option and try for a while.